# Would an external DVD drive work with an LCD TV?

Tags: dvd, tv, external-drive

I want to buy an external DVD drive, but I also want to use it to play videos on an LCD TV. Is this possible? Would the TV be able to interact with the drive over the USB port? Or is a DVD player a must in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exteral DVD player would be a better idea. TV's with a USB Port have very limited support as it is, the one in my TV will only recognise FAT32 partitions, along with wma, mp4 and wma files. As the drive would also need drivers, it's best to get both (DVD players can be very cheap now)

Comment: Thanks. The information about USB support is new to me (especially the FAT32 tip).

Comment: more expensive TV's MAY support different file systems, but they still will be highly unlikely to support a DVD drive. Good idea though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.
I have an LG GP40NB40 and it works with my LG Television which has USB port to play multimedia content from it.
Remember to push 2 seconds the button with the tray open to switch to USB memory mode,
or your television will not recognize it.
Neat feature, no power adapter needed, it works with just USB power.
It comes with a dual-head USB cable for extra power, may be needed when burning (didn't try)

Comment: Does it play standard video DVDs or only encoded media files such as mp3, avi, mkv...